# PHP function similar to this JavaScript function

Tags: php, javascript, function, preg-replace

I need a similar function in PHP for this JavaScript function

```
text = text.replace(/ffc/g, "Hello");
```

I think preg_replace will do, but i'm not sure how to write the expression..

I want the regular expression similar to `/ffc/g` which is above, What I need exactly is to match the full word and case when performing the replace...

Answer (score 5):

```
$text = preg_replace('/ffc/', 'replacement text',  $subject);
```

The online manual for PHP is pretty amazing, and one of the languages best features:

http://php.net/preg_replace

Comment: Invalid expression, invalid usage of [`preg_replace`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and finally... using regular rxpressions for so simple task.

Comment: Maybe the OP is just asking for the regular expression replacement function equivalent in PHP. I also think referring to php.net is a fantastic idea, given how robust the online manual is.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`str_replace`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function like so:

```
$text = str_replace('ffc', 'Hello', $text);
```

Using regexp here is huge overuse.

Comment: seeing as his replacement example is pretty meaningless I'm fairly sure thats not exactly what he wants to do - its more likely "how do I do regular expression replacing in PHP"

Comment: Thanks.. but I want to match the case and also the full word when performing the replace

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace();
will do.

> **Explaination:**

```
preg_replace  (  mixed $pattern  ,  mixed $replacement  ,  mixed $subject  [,  int $limit = -1  [,  int &$count  ]] )
```

> ```
> The pattern to search for. It can be either a string or an array with
> ```
>
> strings.
>
> ```
> The e modifier makes preg_replace() treat the replacement
> ```
>
> parameter as PHP code after the
>   appropriate references substitution is
>   done. Tip: make sure that replacement
>   constitutes a valid PHP code string,
>   otherwise PHP will complain about a
>   parse error at the line containing
>   preg_replace().
>
> The string or an array with strings to
>   replace. If this parameter is a string
>   and the pattern parameter is an array,
>   all patterns will be replaced by that
>   string. If both pattern and
>   replacement parameters are arrays,
>   each pattern will be replaced by the
>   replacement counterpart. If there are
>   fewer elements in the replacement
>   array than in the pattern array, any
>   extra patterns will be replaced by an
>   empty string.
>
> ```
> replacement may contain references of the form \\n or (since PHP 4.0.4)
> ```
>
> $n, with the latter form being the
>   preferred one. Every such reference
>   will be replaced by the text captured
>   by the n'th parenthesized pattern. n
>   can be from 0 to 99, and \0 or $0
>   refers to the text matched by the
>   whole pattern. Opening parentheses are
>   counted from left to right (starting
>   from 1) to obtain the number of the
>   capturing subpattern. To use backslash
>   in replacement, it must be doubled
>   ("\\" PHP string).
>
> ```
> When working with a replacement pattern where a backreference is
> ```
>
> immediately followed by another number
>   (i.e.: placing a literal number
>   immediately after a matched pattern),
>   you cannot use the familiar \1
>   notation for your backreference. \11,
>   for example, would confuse
>   preg_replace() since it does not know
>   whether you want the \1 backreference
>   followed by a literal 1, or the \11
>   backreference followed by nothing. In
>   this case the solution is to use
>   \${1}1. This creates an isolated $1
>   backreference, leaving the 1 as a
>   literal.
>
> ```
> When using the e modifier, this function escapes some characters
> ```
>
> (namely ', ", \ and NULL) in the
>   strings that replace the
>   backreferences. This is done to ensure
>   that no syntax errors arise from
>   backreference usage with either single
>   or double quotes (e.g.
>   'strlen(\'$1\')+strlen("$2")'). Make
>   sure you are aware of PHP's string
>   syntax to know exactly how the
>   interpreted string will look like.
>
> The string or an array with strings
>   to search and replace.
>
> ```
> If subject is an array, then the search and replace is performed on
> ```
>
> every entry of subject, and the return
>   value is an array as well.
>
> The maximum possible replacements for
>   each pattern in each subject string.
>
> If specified, this variable will be
>   filled with the number of replacements
>   done.
>   Defaults to -1 (no limit).
>
> preg_replace() returns an array if
>   the subject parameter is an array, or
>   a string otherwise.
>
> If matches are found, the new subject
>   will be returned, otherwise subject
>   will be returned unchanged or NULL if
>   an error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your requirement of replacing the full word, I'd suggest the following:

```
$text = preg_replace ('/\bffc\b/', 'Hello', $text);
```

Replaces all instances of the 'ffc', and is case-sensitive

Answer (score -2):

```
str_replace($needle, $replacement, $haystack);
```

Comment: There is no such modifier like `g` in [PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) also using regexp for simple replace is overuse.

Comment: Who said anything about a regular expression?